# Lagrange Multiplier to find minimum value

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Find the minimum cost of a rectangular box of volume $180 \text{ cm}^3$ whose top and bottom cost $9$ cents per $\text{cm}^2$ and whose sides cost $5$ cents per $\text{cm}^2$.

**My approach:**

The given volume $V=180\text{ cm}^3$.

let the length $x$ and breadth $x$ height $h$.

$V=x^2y=180$ which implies $y=180/(x^2)$

Total cost $C=9x^2+9x^2+5\cdot (4xy)$ (since whose top and bottom cost $9$ cents per $\text{cm}^2$ and whose sides cost $5$ cents per $\text{cm}^2$)

$C=18x^2+20x\cdot \frac{180}{x^2}$ since $y=\frac{180}{x^2}$.

$C=18x^2+\frac{3600}{x}$

differentiating with respect to x

$C'=36x - \frac{3600}{x^2}$

For minimum cost we set $C'=0$

$36x - \frac{3600}{x^2}=0$ which implies $36x^3=3600$ which implies $x^3=\frac{3600}{36}$

$x=\sqrt[3]{\frac{3600}{36}}=4.641588834$

therefore the minimum cost of a rectangular box of volume is $x=4.641588834$ cents.

The answer is wrong but I have no ideas where is the problem. Any idea?

Comment: Not *another* box/aquarium problem. Have a look at the related problems at right, such as http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1384734/265466. The details of the numbers are different, the process to arrive at a solution is exactly the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1384734/265466 and many others.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you've done is not [Lagrange Multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), but more of a substitution method for constrained optimization. See the difference between section 2.4 and 2.5 in the [link](http://home.uchicago.edu/~vlima/courses/econ201/pricetext/chapter2.pdf) I provide.

---

Let's continue from your methodology. You've found the correct value for $x$, **However:**

Note that $x$ is **not the final answer** since you are asked to find the minimum **cost, not the corresponding length** ($x$ is in $\text{cm}$, not cents).

Therefore, you must find evaluate $C$ by simply substituting $x$ into the function for the cost you derived:
$$C=18x^2+\frac{3600}{x}$$
That should give you the correct answer.

---

Alternatively, if you want to use Lagrange Multipliers, you have your function to minimize:
$$f(x,y)=18x^2+20xy$$
And your constraint:
$$g(x,y)=x^2y-180$$
Applying them gives the Lagrangian:
$$\mathcal{L}(x,y,\lambda)=f(x,y)-\lambda\cdot g(x,y)=18x^2+20xy-\lambda (x^2y-180)$$
Evaluating partial derivatives and setting each equal to zero gives the following system of equations:
$$\begin{cases} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x}=36x+20y-2xy\lambda=0 \\ \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y}=20x-\lambda x^2=0 \\ \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \lambda}=-x^2y+180=0\end{cases}$$
Which you can solve, and then substitute the values of $x$ and $y$ to obtain the same answer for the cost $C$, which is equivalent to $f(x,y)$.

Comment: I plug in x = 4.6415 into C and I have C = 1163.3947, but that is still wrong. I cannot figure out which step is wrong . Any comment ?

Comment: @RoundSticBallPen Perhaps it might be helpful if you provided us with the correct answer (If you have it).

Comment: @RoundSticBallPen If it is an online input system, you may have to input the **exact** answer instead of an approximated one.